# Is it possible to initialize an array variable in a for loop (python)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

Scenario: A dictionary contains many lists that I want to extract.
Psuedocode: E.g.

```
Dict = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[4,5,6]}
```

Result, I want to create an array named after the keys in a for loop. Is it possible?
I want `a = [1,2,3], b = [2,3,4], c=[4, 5, 6]` without having to type the a = [], b = [], c = [] and append them individually, is there anyway to do this in a for loop automatically?

Result:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [4,5,6]
```

My current solution:
Create a class

```
class Container:
     def __init__(self):
         self.k = []
result = [Container() for i in range(4)]
for i,k in enumerate(Dict.keys()):
    result[i] = Dict[k]
```

Is there any faster solution?

Comment: TLDR of the duplicate: You can use ``globals().update(Dict)`` but please reconsider whether you really should.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exec, but note that this is a possible security risk and not recommended:

```py
Dict = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[4,5,6]}

for k,v in Dict.items():
    exec(k+" = v")
```

Edit:

The security risk is basically somebody putting code into `Dict` and thereby trying to get it executed. A harmless test you could make is to add `d:os.getcwd()` to `Dict`, hoping that the program already imports `os`, then you'll later have a variable `d` with your working directory. You could for example use something like this to read file contents and send them to somebody else.
A more malign user could try to execute code that removes certain files from your hard disk, or installs trojans, etc. To be honest I did not manage to do really malign things while giving it a short try, because naively doing things like `d:import os; print("Hello world")` lead to a syntax error, but there most likely are ways to do bad stuff using some libraries I did not think of (or other tricks). For a better read, I'd refer to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191623/best-practices-for-execution-of-untrusted-code) and the links in the first answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate the risk involved?

Comment: @elpsyCongroo: If outside code or data can change the dictionary keys then `k` could end up being something like `'format-hard-disk(); x'`. Basically this: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Ah yeah, good old Bobby tables, didn't even have to look that one up. ;)

Comment: But getting access to the Dict on my computer requires access to my computer right? So Once I restarted my Python console, the Dict is deleted, right?

Comment: That is correct, as long as you remain in sole and full control of `Dict`, this is safe.
It becomes dangerous if you read in something from files somebody as access to, or if you use some other API and fill `Dict` with something from the internet, for example, or in open-source projects where somebody might inject code that you didn't review thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, i think my own solution works best at the moment.

Comment: That's a fair assessment, although I don't see how it satisfies the requirements stated in your question; I get `result == [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], <__main__.Container at 0x25876c76f70>]`, which is quite far from three lists `a, b, c`. Maybe just restructure your code to work with the original `Dict`?

Comment: My code works but you need to know which index corresponds to what